# Substituir um simbolo por outro no PHP

Tags: php, replace

Eu estou querendo substituir todos os sinais de `+` para `vírgula` com o PHP.
Eu estou fazendo desta forma:

```
$q = $_GET['q'];
$string = str_replace("+",",","$q");
```

Isto esta retirando o sinal de `+`, mas me retorna um espaço vazio em vez da vírgula.
Se alguém puder me dizer oque estou fazendo de errado.

Comment: e o conteúdo de `q` vem da onde?

Answer (score 1):

O que deve ocorrer é que o `+` representa espaço, por isso quando utiliza o `$_GET['q']` ele contem espaço, e não o simbolo de `+`. Essa troca, interna do PHP, faz com que o `str_replace` não funcione, pois não existe qualquer `+` naquele ponto.

Para que o seu código funcione você deve substituir o `+` por `%2B`, então se você tem:

```
https://site.com/q=1+2+3
```

Troque para:

```
https://site.com/q=1%2B2%2B3
```

Seu código irá funcionar, pois o `%2B` é o código hexadecimal para `+`, em ASCII, ele não será convertido para espaço pelo PHP.

---

Para converter automaticamente poderá usar o `http_build_query`, que segue a RFC3986, se especificado:

```
echo 'https://site.com?' . http_build_query(['q' => '1+2+3'], '', '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);
```

*Por exemplo. Isso irá resultar o URL mencionado acima, que irá funcionar.*