# Como pegar os valores dentro de várias tags?

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte página html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Exemplo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="text">Valor 1</div>
        <div id="text">Valor 2</div>
        <div id="text">Valor 3</div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Estou usando a seguinte função em PHP para pegar o texto entre uma tag:

```
    function capturar($string, $start, $end) {
    $str = explode($start, $string);
    $str = explode($end, $str[1]);
    return $str[0];
}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
 <?php
$url = file_get_contents('http://localhost/exemplo.html');
$valor = capturar($url, '<div id="text">', '</div>');
echo $valor;
```

Porem, quando tem mais de uma tag idêntica com o texto entre elas diferente, ela só pega o texto entre a primeira tag.

O que eu faria para para pegar todos textos entre essa tag `(<div id="text">, </div>)` ?

Comment: Usando regex conseguirias algo bem mais preciso.

Comment: É altamente recomendado não mudar a pergunta, sendo que há uma resposta para tal. Faça uma nova pergunta caso tenha outra dúvida.

Comment: Pedro, se tem outros questionamentos, abra uma nova pergunta, mas não edite alterando completamente uma já existente, principalmente quando já há respostas. Aliás, [você já pediu isso aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/256483/5878). Aproveite e faça o [tour] para entender como o site funciona.

Answer (score 4):

O PHP já tem funções nativas para tratar HTML. Não acredito que usar REGEX, para essa finalidade,  seja recomendado.

Primeiro você pega o HTML, usando `file_get_contents` ou `cURL`, como está usando o `file_get_contents` deixarei assim:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://localhost/exemplo.html');
```

Depois, supondo que não houve nenhum erro ao obter o conteúdo, crie um DOM e um XPath desse conteúdo, para assim termos como manipula-lo:

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML($html);
$XPath = new DomXPath($DOM);
```

Agora, basta pesquisar o que desejamos, usando XPath:

```
$divs = $XPath->query('//div[@id="text"]');
```

Se isso for encontrado, podemos fazer um loop. Já para exibir o conteúdo usamos o `nodeValue`:

```
foreach($divs as $div){
    echo $div->nodeValue;
    echo '<br>';
}
```

---

No final terá:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://localhost/exemplo.html');

$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML($html);
$XPath = new DomXPath($DOM);

$divs = $XPath->query('//div[@id="text"]');

foreach($divs as $div){
    echo $div->nodeValue;
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Resultado:

```
Valor 1
Valor 2
Valor 3
```

---

Além disso, você não deve repetir um mesmo `id`. Os ids devem ser únicos, ter mais de um elemento com o nome de `texto` é incorreto.

Comment: Não, tá certo. Me confundi com outra pergunta que ele fez. Muita confusão rs.